# I am not able to display the values and result in the textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on this small project which has a function that is called when the calculate button is clicked and the total salary is calculated, including the utilities, rent and tax. I have prepared the function and the html form but I am not able to display the values into the respective textbox not the total salary.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function SalCal(){
        var sal=document.getElementById("bsTxt");

            if(sal.value == "" || sal.value.length < 0) 
            {
                alert("Basic Salary is missing");
            }
            else if(sal.value != "" || sal.value.length > 0)
            {
                var u = sal * 0.1;
                var r = sal * 0.08;
                var t = sal * 0.02;
                document.getElementById("uti").value = u;
                document.getElementById("h_rent").value = r;
                document.getElementById("tax_p").value = t;
                var calTotal = (u + r) - t;

                document.getElementById("total_sal").value = calTotal;
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <h1>Employee Salary Calculator</h1>
    </div><br /> 
    <br />
    <div>
        <h3>Welcome to online salary calculator</h3>
    </div><br />
    <br />

    <form>
        Employee ID:
        <input type="text" name="EmpId" value="BC123456789">
        <span class="note">*Suppose your own VUID is as EmployeeID</span>
        <br>
        EmployeeName:
        <input type="text" name="EmpName" value="Ali Javed">
        <br>
        Father Name:
        <input type="text" name="FName" value="Javed Ahamed">
        <br>
        Gender:
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked>Female<br>
        CNIC:
        <input type="tel" name="cnic" value="33100-8565814-1" pattern="[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{1}" required>
        <span class="note">*Eg:12345-0123456-1</span>
        <br>
        Basic Salary*:
        <input type="number" name="salary" value="" id="bsTxt" required><br>
        Utilities*:
        <input type="number" name="utility" id="uti" ><br>
        House Rent*:
        <input type="number" name="rent" id="h_rent"> <br>
        Tax Percentage*:
        <input type="number" name="tax" id="tax_p"><br>
        Total Salary*:
        <input type="number" name="totalSalary" id="total_sal"><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="SalCal()">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Reset">


    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things

1. sal is a string , use parseInt to convert it to number otherwise you cannot do multiplication and that will result in `NaN`
2. on form submit use the event object and `e.preventDefault` to submit the form and do the manipulation

```js
function SalCal(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var sal = parseInt(document.getElementById("bsTxt").value, 10);

  if (sal == "") {
    alert("Basic Salary is missing");
  } else if (sal != "") {
    var u = sal * 0.1;
    var r = sal * 0.08;
    var t = sal * 0.02;
    document.getElementById("uti").value = u;
    document.getElementById("h_rent").value = r;
    document.getElementById("tax_p").value = t;
    var calTotal = (u + r) - t;
    document.getElementById("total_sal").value = calTotal;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Employee Salary Calculator</h1>
</div><br />
<br />
<div>
  <h3>Welcome to online salary calculator</h3>
</div><br />
<br />

<form>
  Employee ID:
  <input type="text" name="EmpId" value="BC123456789">
  <span class="note">*Suppose your own VUID is as EmployeeID</span>
  <br> EmployeeName:
  <input type="text" name="EmpName" value="Ali Javed">
  <br> Father Name:
  <input type="text" name="FName" value="Javed Ahamed">
  <br> Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked>Female<br> CNIC:
  <input type="tel" name="cnic" value="33100-8565814-1" pattern="[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{1}" required>
  <span class="note">*Eg:12345-0123456-1</span>
  <br> Basic Salary*:
  <input type="number" name="salary" value="" id="bsTxt" required><br> Utilities*:
  <input type="number" name="utility" id="uti"><br> House Rent*:
  <input type="number" name="rent" id="h_rent"> <br> Tax Percentage*:
  <input type="number" name="tax" id="tax_p"><br> Total Salary*:
  <input type="number" name="totalSalary" id="total_sal"><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="SalCal(event)">
  <br>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">


</form>
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here `var sal=document.getElementById("bsTxt");` You are getting an object.

But here `var u = sal * 0.1;` You trying to multiply a number and object.

You should get the value first.The code should be like,

```
var u = sal.value * 0.1;
var r = sal.value * 0.08;
var t = sal.value * 0.02;
```

And prevent your form from submitting, By adding `e.preventDefault();` or 
`<form onsubmit='javascript:return false;'>`

Answer (score 0):

```
var u = sal * 0.1;
var r = sal * 0.08;
var t = sal * 0.02;
```

Replace `sal` with `sal.value`.

Also use add `debugger;` to help easily debug these problems. Can read more about that here - https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/4eae24

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies in  `var u = sal * 0.1;` this line, and sal is string.

change your code like below:

```js
    function SalCal(){
        var sal=document.getElementById("bsTxt");

            if(sal.value == "" || sal.value.length < 0) 
            {
                alert("Basic Salary is missing");
            }
            else if(sal.value != "" || sal.value.length > 0)
            {
                // var u = sal * 0.1;
                // var r = sal * 0.08;
                // var t = sal * 0.02;
                var u = parseInt(sal.value)  * 0.1;
                var r = parseInt(sal.value)  * 0.08;
                var t = parseInt(sal.value)  * 0.02;
                document.getElementById("uti").value = u;
                document.getElementById("h_rent").value = r;
                document.getElementById("tax_p").value = t;
                var calTotal = (u + r) - t;

                document.getElementById("total_sal").value = calTotal;
                return false; 
            }
        }
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Employee Salary Calculator</h1>
    </div><br /> 
    <br />
    <div>
        <h3>Welcome to online salary calculator</h3>
    </div><br />
    <br />

    <form>
        Employee ID:
        <input type="text" name="EmpId" value="BC123456789">
        <span class="note">*Suppose your own VUID is as EmployeeID</span>
        <br>
        EmployeeName:
        <input type="text" name="EmpName" value="Ali Javed">
        <br>
        Father Name:
        <input type="text" name="FName" value="Javed Ahamed">
        <br>
        Gender:
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked>Female<br>
        CNIC:
        <input type="tel" name="cnic" value="33100-8565814-1" pattern="[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{1}" required>
        <span class="note">*Eg:12345-0123456-1</span>
        <br>
        Basic Salary*:
        <input type="number" name="salary" value="" id="bsTxt" required><br>
        Utilities*:
        <input type="number" name="utility" id="uti" ><br>
        House Rent*:
        <input type="number" name="rent" id="h_rent"> <br>
        Tax Percentage*:
        <input type="number" name="tax" id="tax_p"><br>
        Total Salary*:
        <input type="number" name="totalSalary" id="total_sal"><br>

        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="SalCal()">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Reset">


    </form>
```